# ReactJS Springboot JVMs and Proxies

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have four API calls.

```
fetch1 = () => {
  return fetch('http://URL1:PORT1/api/1/' + this.queryParams.mdn, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
};

fetch2 = () => {
  return fetch('http://URL1:PORT1/api/2/' + this.state.customerId + '/' + this.state.accountNum, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
};


  fetch3 = () => {
    return fetch('http://URL1:PORT1/api/3/' + this.state.customerId + '/' + this.state.accountNum, {
      method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res2 => res2.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  };

  fetch4 = () => {
    return fetch('http://URL1:PORT1/api/4/' + this.queryParams.mdn, {
      method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res2 => res2.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  };
```

The "problem" I have is understanding proxies and routing. There are a few JVMs I may need to hit. If one goes down, I hit another. The problem is, with CORS, I usually have to type in the URL into the fetch that I am hitting exactly --> which is usually the server my code resides on.

If I have a total of TWO URLs and TWO PORTS (just incase I need to "bounce" a JVM), how can my fetch know that?

If URL1:PORT1 goes down, I need to hit URL2:PORT2 under the same routes you see above.

Any help or guidance on this would be so helpful!!

Comment: I dont know if i understand you correctly but adding ``Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yoursitename.com`` to server responses would help you.

Comment: I have to hit my soringboot server bc that will call the apis located on another server.its the same as says /API/1/ would hit localhost:8080... Unless it's down, it'll hit 8081

Comment: I tried adding cors statements, it doesn't work